# AS3 Caling MC on Parent Timeline from Child

Tags: actionscript-3

I'd like to find best code referencing movie clip on parent's timeline shortly. It aimed to set alpha and another properties of that visualization movie clip outside child.

I've try using **MovieClip(parent)** but failed.

Please help

Comment: This article would be a good start: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e26.html